Raspberry Pi 4 stopped booting after the last `apt upgrade`
The boot screen on the Pi 4 looks as follows. Given that it is saying no EFI partition found, I tried to check for media error on the SD card by mounting it on my mac, but disk utils says everything looks ok. I run Ubuntu on this Pi
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
VERSION_CODENAME=noble
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian



Indicates power supply or SD issues

I changed the power supply, and no change.

that just leaves sd issues, or the power supply
